# Best way to trigger shutdown/restart from metro app in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm just getting started with Windows 8 app development. As a first project I've created a metro app that should be able to shutdown, restart logoff a user from the computer. The interface is all done, but I'm not sure how to go about shutting it down. Is it possible to use the following and if so do you have an example?

```
%windir%\System32\shutdown.exe /s /t 0
```

Or is there something in the APi I could call? If not could I perhaps include a .bat file in the project and call that to initiate shutdown?

Many thanks

Chris

Comment: Is this a 'real' metro app, i.e. Store app in JS or C#? Or just a desktop app using the new API?

Comment: I'm open to suggestions :D but probably a store app in HTML5 CSS3 and JS so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge this is not possible, and it is certainly not possible using the method you outlined above.  Windows Store apps (the apps formerly known as "Metro") run in a heavily sandboxed enviropnment, and as such you don't get any access to the Windows directory in order to call `shutdown.exe`.  The security model in place (should) make(s) it virtually impossible to complete tasks like a reboot or shutdown operation - that is (and should be) firmly in the domain of the user to decide rather than an app.

Comment: Thanks for the concise response. I've obviously misunderstood the purpose of the store. Is there another way then to get a tile onto the metro UI that can shutdown, restart, and logoff a user. Perhaps that people can install via their desktop and then it appears in Metro?

I do apologise ...I started looking into Win8 app development this morning so: "wet behind the ears" doesn't even come close.

Comment: You can certainly add an icon to the start screen, but it isn't as easy as you might think.  Cretae a shortcut on your desktop and them move it to the c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs folder.  The icon will be ugly, though.  In short, I think you're on a hiding to nothing trying to replicate behaviour that already exists.  Sorry, just my opinion, for what that's worth (not much).

Comment: Thanks for the opinion, I know its duplicating functionality that exists already but thought it puts that functionality in an easy to reach place. Ho hum. I'll have to think of something else to try for now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Easier to reach than pressing Win+I and selecting Power->Shutdown?

Comment: @ma_il. The point is that most windows users don't know what shortcuts do what. For me and you, Win+I or Ctrl + Alt + Delete or Alt + F4 on the desktop are easy ways. But for your average run of the mill user? They will probably go the charms bar root in which case its well out the way. If there was a power tile on the metro ui a user could go back to metro, click power and select shutdown. As it happens though...its not possible so its a moot point.